# I've set up a password protected folder on my website and it works in Chrome and FF but not IE

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer

The error i get in IE is this:

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

```
Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_hive/3.6 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at www.**************.com Port 80
```

It doesn't ever prompt me for my username and password.

In chrome and ff; i get the pop up and it asks me for username and password because you need authorization to visit this page.

The page that IE drops me on is a secondary page I would land on in chrome or FF if i used the wrong credentials.

My .htaccess doesn't have much to it, it looks like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
AuthName "PRO"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

#AuthName "PRO"
#AuthUserFile "/home/******/public_html/pro/.htpasswd"
#AuthType Basic
#require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 default
AuthUserFile "/home/******/.htpasswds/public_html/pro/passwd"
```

It's a magento page/store. (linux, apache, mysql, php)

If there is anything else i could provide to help figure out where this problem is deriving from than please feel free to ask. I'm not really sure why it's breaking only in IE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Fiddler or IE's F12 Developer tools to watch exactly what is coming back from the server (`WWW-Authenticate` header on the 401) and what is sent from the client (`Authorization` header on the request sent in response to the 401). More than likely this is a caching issue; Basic credentials are cached for the lifetime of the process.

Comment: It may be just another problem of damn IE , but could you say which version of IE your talking about ? but at all , the Rewrite Rules on htaccess file run on the server and it depends to your server abilities . I don't think there is any other way to authorize by htaccess

Comment: I was on IE 10 earlier and it didn't work and now i'm on IE 11.

Comment: I've just tested on IE 7! It worked correctly ... try the way by Cpanel By **password protect directories icon in security block**

Comment: @EricLaw, i do not have enough reputation points to upload an image so here are my only errors.  http://tinypic.com/r/9iheea/8

Comment: I originally tried just using that method. @mkrowling

Comment: @RAD: You need to look at the `Network` tab in F12, or better yet, use Fiddler.

Comment: @EricLaw, I had no errors in my network tab on the left hand menu of developer tools. I just downloaded fiddler and i'm reading into how to use it.